# Angular 7 + Material - apply material "directive" on HTML5 element?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular7

Let's look at this:

```
<a mat-list-item routerLink="..." routerLinkActive="active-class">Link</a>
```

So here Angular allows to embed "mat-list-item" as `<a>` attribute.

Is there similar syntax for every other Material component?

Say:

```
<mat-toolbar>
     <header></header>
</mat-toolbar>
```

Can I somehow do this:

```
<header mat-toolbar></header>
```

Is `<a mat-list-item>` special case, or is it something that works for all `mat-...`. How?

https://material.angular.io/components/toolbar/api

Here it says "Selector" and "Exported as:" - shouldn't second work like I want it to?

Comment: _"Exported as"_ means that the component can be referenced as what it is exported as. (For example, you can assign a reference to a toolbar and set the value of that reference to `matToolbar`.)

Comment: @Edric this is absolutely not the case. the mat-list-item is a directive, sometimes elements are components, sometimes they're directives only available on certain elements.

Comment: @bryan60 Oops, I didn't consider directives. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not standard functionality.  The mat-list-item is exposed as a directive on anchor tags for SEO purposes.

The docs will be explicit when there is a directive available.

Comment: In the docs for the list item component, the selectors are explicitly marked: https://material.angular.io/components/list/api#MatListItem

Comment: @Edric yes, [a]mat-list-item is the selector that allows it to be used as a directive.

Comment: Very nice and clear answer. Thank for link @Edric. Now I am sure what to look for.